# How to Publish a “Raster catalog”, and is an image Server extension will be required in this case?

Tags: arcgis-server, raster-catalog

I have a Raster catalog that contains a number of images, and I want to publish it using ArcGIS server 10.3.1, when I right click on the Raster catalog I cannot find Share as image service! In the mosaic dataset when I click on the dataset I can see publish as Image service. So the question is How can I published a Raster catalog dataset if it’s possible, and do I need to have an image server extension to publish it?! 
 I cannot find any documentation about the topic.

[image]
[image]

Comment: One of the features of raster mosaics is that they can be published (with an Image Server extension). Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: Vince, who told you that there is two questions here !

Comment: Any question with "and" in it indicates two questions. 1) How can I publish a raster catalog as a service 2) How does Image Server Extension licensing work?  These are completely unrelated, as only a little research would indicate.  Questions here at GIS SE are supposed to be researched **before** posting.